# Time out error in sql query executed in vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have 1 lakh (100000) data in my database. If I try to delete content details in content_details table, I found time out error.
I have list of content ids in string builder.
Error:

```
Timestamp: 10/29/2013 11:33:54 AM
Message: Exception thrown from:
    Thread was being aborted.
    at SNIReadSyncOverAsync(SNI_ConnWrapper* , SNI_Packet** , Int32 )
    at SNINativeMethodWrapper.SNIReadSyncOverAsync(SafeHandle pConn, IntPtr& packet, Int32 timeout)
```

Event code:

```
Sql = "DELETE FROM content_details WHERE content_id IN (select id from dbo.splitid(@content_id, ','))" 
Using con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(m_RequestInfo.ConnectionString) 
    Using cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(Sql, con) 
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        con.Open()
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@content_id", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = contIdList.ToString()
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 600
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: You should be able to edit your question and add the code from your comment.  That will make it easier for everyone to read.

Comment: @user2739544 Please format your code with your comment we can read and understand your problem

Comment: Set `cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;`(infinite) and wait until it has finished.

Comment: Now i edited please help me

Comment: If we set commantimeout value for common 600. That is not affect above error.

Comment: avoid using 'IN' try to achieve it by JOIN query....

Comment: What kid of database is this?  The syntax in the sub query looks odd to me.